# How to fix module to get correct output?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that I am not splitting correctly. I know that I need to try replacing a comma that is not followed by a whitespace.

**CSV file:**

```
movieId,title,genre
1,"American President, The (1995)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
2,"Creation, The creator(xxxx)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
3,"Destruction, The destroyer(xxxxx)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

```js
function csv_json(csvFile) {
    const _ = require('lodash');
    const fs = require('fs')
    const csvData = fs.readFileSync(csvFile, 'utf8');
    'use strict';

    var csvObject = csvToObjectArray(csvData);

    // console.log(csvObject);

    function csvToObjectArray(data) {
        var csvRowArray    = data.split(/\n/); // spilt by new lines
        var headerCellArray = trimQuotes(csvRowArray.shift().split(','));
        var objectArray     = [];

        while (csvRowArray.length) {

            var rowCellArray = trimQuotes(csvRowArray.shift().split(','));
            var rowObject    = _.zipObject(headerCellArray, rowCellArray);
            objectArray.push(rowObject);
        }
        return objectArray;
    }

    function trimQuotes(stringArray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            stringArray[i] = _.trim(stringArray[i], '"');
        }
        return stringArray;
    }
    return csvObject
}

module.exports = csv_json ;
```

```
//js file

const mod = require('./syncCsv_Json.js');
const data = mod('./movieTest.csv')
const fs = require('fs')


 console.log(data)
/*
output:
[ { movieId: '1',
    title: 'American President',
    genre: ' The (1995)' },
  { movieId: '2', title: 'Creation', genre: ' The creator(xxxx)' },
  { movieId: '3',
    title: 'Destruction',
    genre: ' The destroyer(xxxxx)' },
  { movieId: '', title: undefined, genre: undefined } ]
*/
```

**I expect :**

```
[ { movieId: '1',
    title: "American President, The (1995)",
    genre:'Comedy|Drama|Romance' },
  { movieId: '2',
    title: "The creator(xxxx) Creation",
    genre: ' Comedy|Drama|Romance' },
  { movieId: '3',
    title: "Destruction The destroyer(xxx)",
    genre: ' Comedy|Drama|Romance' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since fields can contain delimiters (commas), simple line splitting is no good. So better use the already proven parser and converter. For example, [`Keyang/node-csvtojson`](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson):

```js
csv()
  .fromString(`movieId,title,genre
1,"American President, The (1995)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
2,"Creation, The creator(xxxx)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
3,"Destruction, The destroyer(xxxxx)",Comedy|Drama|Romance`)
  .subscribe((jsonObj) => {
    jsonObj.genre = jsonObj.genre.split('|')
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson/d41f44aa/browser/csvtojson.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: so for my assignment Im suppose to create a csv_json module or I would use csvtojson